# Good practices to improve React User Interface performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently facing a performance issue with one of my React application. Are there any Good Practices to follow to improve 'reactivity' of the User Interface.

I can for instance reduce the number of `JavaScript in JSX` conditions,
such as `{ carIsRed === true ? <RedCar /> : <BlackCar /> }` but most of them are required.

I'm using `react-scrollbar-x` to display large tables , it may impact the overall performance of my app.

Are there other points to focus on, that could improve performance in User Interface?

Here's a part of my Component :

```
      {element.description.length > 0 ?
        <Popup
          trigger={
            <Table.Cell style={{ verticalAlign:'middle', maxWidth: '100px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }}>
              {(editProject === false) || (editProject === true && editProjectIndex !== index) ?
                element.description
                : null}
              {editProject === true && editProjectIndex === index ?
                <Form>
                  <TextArea
                    autoHeight
                    placeholder='Description'
                    value={this.state.newProjectDescription}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeNewProjectDescription}
                  />
                </Form>
                : null}
            </Table.Cell>
          }
          content={element.description}
          basic
        /> :
        <Table.Cell style={{ verticalAlign:'middle', maxWidth: '100px', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' }} negative={element.description.length === 0}>
          {(editProject === false) || (editProject === true && editProjectIndex !== index) ?
            element.description
            : null}
          {editProject === true && editProjectIndex === index ?
            <Form>
              <TextArea
                autoHeight
                placeholder='Description'
                value={this.state.newProjectDescription}
                onChange={this.handleChangeNewProjectDescription}
              />
            </Form>
            : null}
        </Table.Cell>
      }
```

[image]

Here's my component interface for which I'd like to improve rendering process

Comment: React doesn't have performance issues until you start getting into thousands of components. Not much we can do to help without seeing a specific example.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll update my question.

Comment: "I'm currently facing a performance issue with one of my React application...", care to specify what the performance issue is exactly and what your expected performance _would_ look like?

Comment: @Pineda Excellent point, my bad

Comment: "It seems a bit slow" and "expecting it to render faster" aren't actionable. There's no way to help with the information provided. Note that simple conditionals don't really affect the rendering performance much. It's also pretty hard to read. For example, I would not have the length check as an embedded ternary; break it out into a single `if` statement and return the `<Popup>` or the `<Table.Cell>` separately. Then you can break each of those down further, probably into small stateless components, and improve readability a *ton*, which would make it easier to reason about.

Comment: There also seems to be some duplicated code which should be extracted out.

Comment: *Very* roughly, https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/3f32d33e38ccc5fa5a4f7aa9ebf10334

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks a lot, that looks like the the refactoring I need for my whole app. Actually you're right, there're a many redundancies in my code that could be functions, so with this kind of approach I could improve the performance of my application.

Comment: @awzx Not necessarily; the refactor gives you a fighting chance to reason about what's happening (and when, and why). Once you're there, discovering what needs to render when is much easier, then you can progressively enhance with things like `shouldComponentUpdate` and other performance enhancements. Refactoring will actually *incur* performance penalties, although generally very mild ones.

Comment: That depends, but in some cases in my code, I really consider doing that as in other having the conditions in my JSX doesn't seem problematic. I don't think there's one solution to my `problem`, it's more an algorithmic issue.

Comment: Always use profiling tools if you suspect performance issues. Never guess what it might be - premature optimization is a bad idea; if you do with to optimize, use the tools to tell you where exactly you have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package called [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/MultiGrid) for very large tables in React that helps a lot out with render performance.

By the looks of it, react-scrollbar-x is using this.setState() inside a method that is called numerous about of times. which am guessing is the cause of your decreased performance

If you're using Chrome there is a great extension to visualize your app's performance called [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)

Comment: I assumed react-scrollbar-x was the main responsible of this loss of performance. react-virtualized seems to be an awesome alternative!

Comment: Ya theres alot of packages out there that call this.setstate() inside a method like onscroll, onresize or ondrag, which can lead to decreased performance